# How googleDrive and dropbox's folders are made?

Tags: database, google-drive-api, directory, dropbox

You all know that in `GoogleDrive` you can create your own folders to arrange your files. My question is: `how files are allocated to a specific folder`? 
My guess is that when you create a folder, it is added in their database. But how the files are allocated to these folders? What do you think?